# How do I make a Canvas HTML picture bigger without losing resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

My canvas size is 300x150. I don't want to set the measurements any bigger than this because I'd like it fit on mobile phones as well. But i'd like it to scale up on bigger phones, ipads and laptops without losing resolution. The resolution on my canvas pictures have generally been bad and when it scales up it typically gets even worse. Not sure how to solve this problem. Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/uwakcgv0/

Here's the HTML:

```
<canvas width="300" height="150" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 130);
ctx.lineTo(130, 130);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillText("y",18,15);
ctx.fillText("x",135,132);
```

Comment: May be not best solution, but ideally, the area you need to focus on user agent to identify device, but another alternative can be home page will generate a javascript that will get height and width of the device and redirect to your other page that will recongnize your height and width.  you can store the info in session or in browser storage.

Comment: ok thanks. but then how do i draw the canvas so it will adapt to the new size? it seems like when i make the canvas size bigger the drawing is the same size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the canvas size by any factor and then scale the canvas by the same factor (using `ctx.scale()`) to get the desired result.

```js
const SCALING_FACTOR = 2;
    
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.canvas.width = SCALING_FACTOR * canvas.width;
ctx.canvas.height = SCALING_FACTOR * canvas.height;

ctx.scale(SCALING_FACTOR, SCALING_FACTOR);

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 130);
ctx.lineTo(130, 130);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillText("y", 18, 15);
ctx.fillText("x", 135, 132);
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="150" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```